# Spring MVC Application Deployment on Tomcat

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat7, tomcat8.5

I'm having an issue running a spring MVC application on a stand-alone tomcat server.

I am using Spring MVC (webmv)ver. 4.2.2, tomcat8.5 (8.5.33), and building with Maven.

The significant files in my project:

a. pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>lb.mi</groupId>
<artifactId>localization-app</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<!-- Maven -->

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Tomcat Specific -->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                <url>http://localhost:9080/manager/text</url>
                    <port>9080</port>
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>
                    <path>/home</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

b. localization-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:component-scan
    base-package="lb.mi" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<!-- Using webjars(Bootstrap, etc...) Expose webjar content as static resources -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="/webjars/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>


<!-- Localization Beans and parameters -->

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="language" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" >
    <property name="interceptors">
       <list>
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
       </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Register the welcome.properties -->
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="welcome" />
</bean>
```

c. web.xml

```
<!-- webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml -->
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/localization-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>



    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

d. HomeController.java

```
package lb.mi;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;

@Controller
public class HomeController extends AbstractController {

@Override
protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("home");
    return model;
}

@RequestMapping(value="test",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showTest()
{
    return "test";
}

}
```

My Server is up and running at port: 9080.

I am deploying to tomcat from Eclipse (Photon), as follows:

right click --> run as --> Maven build --> on Goals: **tomcat7:deploy**

after successfully deploying, I opened the tomcat App Manager console, and verified the deployment:
[image]
No I would like to start the application, I hit the URL:

localhost:9080/home

Unfortunately I could not open the application. I am getting:

404 Not found: The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.
[image]
Any advice greatly appreciated :)

Best,

Comment: Have you tried: `localhost:9080/home/test`

Comment: Hi Jens, and thank you for the quick and prompt response. Indeed it's working, it seems I have completely missed the context path that I have personally set in the dispatcher "localization-servlet.xml" the path "<path>/home</path>". Thanks a million!!!

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: This is only a comment not an answer. So you can‘t accept it

Comment: Understood. Thanks again :)